# Unity Vector3.y varies from actual value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Console and Scene]

Hello everyone,
I'm trying to make a transparent Cube follow the cursor except when the cursor is on the top side of an opaque Cube.

To do this I use a plane(map), parallel to the top side of the cubes. I cast 2 Rays, one of which only hits the plane and the other only hits the opaque cube. Then I compare the two raycasthit points.

If the Opaque cube is not hit or is hit at a point under the plane, the transparent cube moves.

However, when using RaycastHit.point.y to compare the two, the raycasthit of the plane returns a wrong value with RaycastHit.point.y. (Which should always be 0)

When I Log it out in the console the value in the vector object and the y coordinate which is put out are different.

The other raycast does not have this problem.

```
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit raycastHit2, float.MaxValue, mapOverlayLayer)){
            Debug.Log("r2");
            Debug.Log(raycastHit2.point);
            Debug.Log(raycastHit2.point.y);
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit raycastHit, float.MaxValue, gameObjectLayer)){
                Debug.Log("r1");
                Debug.Log(raycastHit.point);
                Debug.Log(raycastHit.point.y);
                GameObject hitObject = raycastHit.transform.gameObject;
                if(hitObject.tag == "GenericMapObject"){
                    if(raycastHit2.point.y <= raycastHit.point.y){
                        Debug.Log("Mapoverlay is lower/equal");
                    }else{
                        Debug.Log("Mapoverlay is higher");
                        MoveCursorCube(raycastHit2.point);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                Debug.Log("Only Mapoverlay");
                MoveCursorCube(raycastHit2.point);
            }
        }
    }
```

I could just compare one raycast to 0 statically, but I'm still interested why this might occur. Any Ideas?

Comment: I suppose you mean these values that say xxxxxE-16 .. which basically means 0.000.......1 which 16 zeros after the comma ... that's ridiculously small compared with your other values .. simply compare against a threshold like `if(point.y <= 0.001f)` which should be more than precise enough for your use case ...

Comment: Besides that the `if(raycastHit2.point.y <= raycastHit.point.y)` should probably be correct anyway

Comment: Ah, ok. Didn't read it correctly then. Ty for the answer :)